# How to tell Core Data Lightweight migration has been successful

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, icloud

Background:

I have an app currently in the appstore that uses a core data datastore - with iCloud.

I have added to fields to an entity and a new entity.

I have setup auto migration and i think it all works. (Nothing crashes)

Is there a way to tell that it works 100%? I assume this is the best approach to such minor changes? I don't want to release with a chance some user will get a crash.

The code to implement the auto migration is the following:

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];
// this needs to match the entitlements and provisioning profile
NSURL *cloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
NSString* coreDataCloudContent = [[cloudURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iLearn_LessonPlans"];
cloudURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:coreDataCloudContent];

//  The API to turn on Core Data iCloud support here.
NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"com.danielanderton.iLearn_LessonPlans.1",    NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey, cloudURL, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,nil];

NSError *error = nil;

[psc lock];
if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
              NSLog(@"error");
}
[psc unlock];
```

Comment: I use the same approach in my iCloud-CoreData app to perform lightweight migration, but it doesn't want to work. Method addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error: always returns Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file upload timed out." And it works well after rollback to previous version of model. Maybe you have any idea what may cause this?